# Using "nonexempt" in different contexts

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

A Google search for "nonexempt" returns a lot of results regarding employees and overtime pay.

However, I did find this word defined in a dictionary, independent of the overtime pay discussion, for example:

> Subject to an obligation, duty, or liability, especially subject to taxation.
>   [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonexempt)

Now, I have a situation where a certain tenant may be exempt from a common area maintenance charge, and I want to express that others are nonexempt. This is a one word formulation that spares me from saying "obligated to pay" or "subject to the payment" (because saying just "obligated" and "subject" seem insufficient).

Can I say **nonexempt** in this context?
As in:

> Show all rented and nonexempt properties.

Comment: Non-exempt is fine but it should probably be hyphenated.

Comment: You are making an _exception_ for some tenants by _waiving_ these charges for them or in other words, they are _exempt_ from these charges. That's how it's usually mentioned. I don't know if you have any specific reason to negate it and say it the other way round. Do you?

Comment: @alwayslearning, yes, it's understood that by default they must pay the charges, but I'm working with a software interface where both states need to have a descriptive term.

Comment: You should not use "nonexempt" unless the context is such that the reader will understand "exempt from what?".  Eg, it could easily mean exempt from certain housing regulations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, ***chargeable*** works here in place of *nonexempt*.

M-W:

> **[chargeable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chargeable)**
>   *adjective*
>
> 2:  liable to be charged: as
>
> b :  suitable to be charged to a particular account
>
> The business lunch was chargeable to the company.

ODO:

> **[chargeable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chargeable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Example sentence:
>
> ‘Yes, you will be chargeable to capital gains on the gift, subject to
>   your current annual exemption allowance of #7100 if the gift is made
>   in this current tax year.’

Comment: hmmm...your example uses a lunch as the topic. But clearly the lunch isn't the one paying, rather being payed for. I need to express that the tenant is required to pay.